# Error #2148: SWF file Cannot acces local resources

Tags: actionscript-3, resources

I'm trying to load a local video to display it and I'm having this error ( Error #2148) at runtime, I have read in many places what this problem is, about flash security and all that stuff but there's no solution anywhere and some people say that it can't be done.

My swf works fine when loading from internet, I have my cross-domain on my server but is completely necessary for me to create a standalone version which can run without internet connection and load the videos from file system.

May be with different compiling options? I'm using Flash Builder 4.6
Any idea how could I achive a local resource loading?

P.D. I know that the trusted folder can resolve the problem but that implies a configuration change in every computer it runs and I need it to be portable like in a USB to run on any computer that has Flash Player.

Comment: Have you tried the compilation by `-use-network=false` parameter?

Comment: http://www.brettwidmann.com/2010/03/how-to-remedy-flex-error-2148/

Comment: I used '-use-network=false' which is what the article said to, but I got an other error with that 'SecurityError: Error #2028: Local-with-filesystem SWF file file:///C:/Users/Desarrollo/Desktop/bin-release/imVideo360.swf cannot access Internet URL http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.6.0.23201/framework_4.6.0.23201.swz.'

Comment: I solved the las problem (ERROR 2028) by setting the flex libraries merged into code instead of RSL like. In project>properties>Build Path>Framework linkage>Merged into code.